# Using PHP, checking if a script is running or not and run other function simultaneously

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, shell-exec

I've PHP function which starts a shell script in my Linux system when a user presses the start button.

```
public function start($id)
{
    $test=Test::find($id);
    $newFile=storage_path('test/script/'.$test->random_string.'.jmx');
    $command = "jmeter -n -t ".$newFile.' -l '.storage_path('test/log/'.$test->random_string).'.log';
    $background= "  > /dev/null 2>&1 &";

    // To allow running test in background
    ob_end_clean();
    header("Connection: close");
    ignore_user_abort(); // optional
    ob_start();
    $size = ob_get_length();
    header("Content-Length: $size");
    ob_end_flush(); // Strange behaviour, will not work
    flush();            // Unless both are called !
    exec($command. $background,$arr);
    // Do processing here
    sleep(30);
}
```

I want another PHP function to know when the script ends and show the response to the user.

```
public function end($id)
{
    $test = Test::find($id);
    $command="ps aux | grep $test->random_string | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'";
    exec($command, $arr);
    while($arr)
    {
        $arr=null;
        sleep(10);
        exec($command, $arr);
    }
    $test->test_running = 0;
    $test->save();
    return response()->json(['msg'=>trans('test.end')]);
}
```

I also want to give my user, option to stop script in middle and show the result of half script.

```
public function stop($id)
{
    $test=Test::find($id);
    $arr=array();
    $background= "  > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
    exec("ps aux | grep $test->random_string | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'", $arr);
    shell_exec('kill '. $arr[1] . $background);
    $test->test_running=0;
    $test->save();
    return response()->json(['msg'=>trans('test.stop')]);
}
```

Problem is while end function is running it doesn't allow stop function(or any other function) to do any processing. Javascript shows response as pending in my browser and sending another request for stop also remain pending until end request is not completed.

Comment: I'm thinking of using multi-threading to run end function and stop function in different threads, don't know if I'm thinking in the right direction?

Comment: I suggest to write an entry to the database or a file in start() just before the exec() and delete it when the external process is finished. In the meantime you can query that entry/file for existence.

Comment: I already have an entry in database for test_running status and I'm setting it while making script for this test and updating it when test ends or is stopped. Problem is to regularly check if this entry is set or unset, I've to run a while statement or thread.

Comment: Maybe this can inspire you: http://www.hit-services.net/aktuelles/long-polling-mit-php-und-jquery.html

Comment: @dev0 Thanks, I solved this problem by removing while statement from end function and calling end function from client side after every 10 sec to check the status. Now I'm able to run stop also.